# Property hides inherited member

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class Tween : MonoBehaviour {
    protected List<TweenItem> items = new List<TweenItem>();
}
public class TweenItem {
    // Properties
}

public class ValueTweenItem : TweenItem {
    // Properties
}
```

In this class I am trying to override `items`:

```
public class ValueTween : Tween{
    protected List<ValueTweenItem> items = new List<ValueTweenItem>();
}
```

When I do this, I get the following warning:

> Assets/simple/Scripts/Util/Tween/ColorTween.cs(9,40): warning CS0108: `Simple.Tween.ColorTween.items' hides inherited member`Simple.Tween.Tween.items'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended

I have tried adding the `override` and `virtual` keywords, but that doesn't work.

How can I make this warning go away?

### Edit

Here is the base:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Simple.Tween{
    public abstract class AbstractTween<T> : MonoBehaviour {
        [SerializeField]
        protected List<T> items = new List<T>();
    }

    public abstract class Tween : AbstractTween<TweenItem>{

        // Common functions here

    }

    public class TweenItem {
        public Component component;
        public float duration = 2f;
        public bool playOnStart = false;

        [HideInInspector]
        public float time = 0f;
        [HideInInspector]
        public bool complete = false;
        [HideInInspector]
        public bool runTween = false;
    }

    public class ValueTweenItem : AbstractTween<ValueTweenItem> {
        public string propertyName;
        public float startValue = 0f;
        public float endValue = 1f;
    }

    public class ColorTweenItem : AbstractTween<ColorTweenItem> {
        public Gradient gradient;
    }
}
```

Then here is the class I am using:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Simple.Tween{
    [AddComponentMenu("Simple/Tween/Value Tween")]
    public class ValueTween : Tween{

        [SerializeField]
        protected List<ValueTweenItem> items = new List<ValueTweenItem>();

        void Update(){
            // Set the color of the object
            foreach(ValueTweenItem item in items){
                if(item.complete || item.runTween == false){
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        void TweenValue(Component item, string field, float value){
            item.GetType().GetProperty(field).SetValue(item, value, null);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: well, what do you want to happen?  By default, `ValueTween` will have a `items` on it, because it inherits from `Tween`, you don't need to declare it.  If you actually want to hide it, use the `new` keyword.

Comment: item now is field you must change it to property public / protected virtual

Comment: i see your edits... what is your question?

Comment: how is `public class ValueTweenItem : AbstractTween<ValueTweenItem> ` compiling?

Comment: your TweenItem classes aren't to extend the abstract Tween... the items look like they are just data classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the SOLID open/closed principle:

Your abstract class is defining a concrete class in it's definition, this is exactly what generics were created to solve:

First, define your abstraction:

```
public abstract class AbstractTween<T> : MonoBehaviour 
{
   protected List<T> items = new List<T>();
   ...
}
```

Now build concrete implementations:

```
public class ValueTween : AbstractTween<ValueTweenItem>
{   ... }
public class Tween : AbstractTween<TweenItem>
{   ... }
```

If all your Items have a property named "Text" and you want all your items to have that property then you'd do this:

```
public interface ITweenItem
{
    string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Now change the abstract class declaration like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractTween<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : ITweenItem
{  ... }
```

EDIT:

Your item classes should be simply defined as:

```
public class ValueTweenItem : TweenItem {
    public string propertyName;
    public float startValue = 0f;
    public float endValue = 1f;
}

public class ColorTweenItem : TweenItem {
    public Gradient gradient;
}
```

`ColorTweenItem` or `ValueTweenItem` seem to extend `TweenItem`

You could if you want add this to the abstract then only `TweenItems` can be used:

```
public abstract class AbstractTween<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : TweenItem
```

Comment: Okay... In the `ValueTween` class I have this `foreach(ValueTweenItem item in items){item.complete}` It can no longer see the property `complete`. What is that?

Comment: actually my above comment was wrong, you should have no problem accessing your items properties.

Comment: Type `Simple.Tween.ColorTweenItem' does not contain a definition for `complete' and no extension method `complete' of type `Simple.Tween.ColorTweenItem' could be found

Comment: I responded on your question.

Comment: `ValueTweenItem` and `ColorTweenItem` both need to extend `TweenItem` fyi

Comment: ok, i am following your code, i updated my answer to fit exactly that.

Comment: Alright it is working now! I need to learn more about generics! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the new keyword as suggested by the compiler.

```
protected new List<ValueTweenItem>  items = new List<ValueTweenItem>();
```

Or use your bass class variable directly (which already instantiated).

Comment: just because it removes the warning, that doesn mean it is necessarily what you want to do.

Comment: @Jonesopolis That is true. The OP was referring to the warning. But of course it's not necessarily what should be done.

Comment: @Moe, certainly not downplaying your answer, just trying to be a good citizen.

Comment: this will inevitably cause some form of crash if done in a class that that has some meat to it..  Remember SOLID, Open to change but closed to modification... that means subclassing in many cases.. like this.